# Mousemove stops triggering when hovering on Popup in Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I need to know when I hover a Popup,

So im using the mousemove event to log the features of the map.

It works fine everywhere, except when I hover the Popup.

As soon as I enter the Popup, there is no event being fired.

I need to know when I'm hovering on it, and a copy a reference of it.

This is the code:

```
map.on('mousemove', function (e) {
  var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point);
  console.log( 'Logging' )

});
```

Very simple, but as soon as the mouse is in the popup, the browser stops loggin.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to caputure *'mousemove'* events also in the popup.
The popup should have the class `mapboxgl-popup` so you could try the following function (example in JQuery):

```
$('.mapboxgl-popup').on('mousemove', function (e) {
  var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point);
  console.log( 'Logging' )
});
```